# Difference between "new" and "gen"

Tags: specman, e

I've done a little playing around in the console and debugger, but I've still got some questions about how new and gen work differently from each other.

What is the difference between using new to generate a struct verse using gen to generate a struct?

Does "gen" use existing allocated memory and "new" allocate new memory? or both allocate memory?

Does "new" generate everything like a "gen" statement?

In cdnshelp it says "new" is a shallow struct, meaning struct fields are not allocated. Is this also true of "gen"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `new` will allocate memory for the struct (except for other internal `struct` fields) and call that struct's `init()` function.

Calling `gen` will do everything `new` does, but also randomize the struct's fields. If any of the struct's fields are other structs, it will call `gen` on them too.

Comment: so new will leave all fields as NULL?

Comment: 'new' initializes default values:
 - Sets the initial value of the struct to NULL.
 - Sets the initial value of lists to (empty), unless the list is a sized list of scalars, in which case it is initialized to the proper size with each item set to the default value.
 - Sets the initial value of all fields of scalar type, including enumerated scalar type, to zero.